# how to use function this.state to send variable to other components on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i still beginner for react and i want to use this function `this.state` to send variable to other component

here is my code. this is my index.html file code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/purpletree_multivendor/buynow/checkout.css" /> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>  

    <script type="text/babel" src="catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/purpletree_multivendor/buynow/App.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

i build file name App.js

```
class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        skipButton: false
    };
    
  }

  changeSkipPage = () => {
    this.setState = {skipButton: true},
    <Home handleClick={this.setState.skipButton} />
  }
  
  render() {
    return (  
        <div>   
            <a onClick={this.changeSkipPage}>
                <span> Skip Login</span>
            </a> 
        </div>  
      )
  }
}

 
class Welcome extends React.Component { 
    render() {
      return (  
          <div>   
              Welcome World
          </div>  
        )
    }
  }

 
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {  
   
    super(props); 
   
    console.log(props)
    
  } 

  render() {   
    return ( 
        // set condition if can get variable handleClick is true. will have condition to change other page 
        // if(variable handleClick is true) {
        //     will call page <Welcome />
        // }else{
        //     still login page
        // }
      )
  }
}
```

so what was i tried to do is, class `Home` is combine component from class `Login` and class `Welcome`. first display is class `Login` if condition is user click skip button, class `Home` the display will change to class `Welcome`

but above code not work. it not send the variable from class `Login` when click skip button to class `Home`

please help.

Comment: `this.state to send variable to other component` - pass it in as a prop

Comment: @Adam thank you for the response. how do i able to do that? sorry

Comment: Show the code where you are rendering App - it often looks like `ReactDom.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))`

Comment: Hi @Adam i already updated it with my index.html file code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing state to child component and it is ok with small apps.

If what you are building is not small then it's recommended to use global state like Redux.

One more thing. it is good to know how class component and it's life cycle hooks work, but it's recommended to use functional components with hooks

Best of luck